# Error at build time with array parameters

Tags: c++, arrays, function, parameters, build

So I am currently learning about arrays and functions and I seem to have ran into a problem. So the goal of my code is to have the user input 10 numbers, store those numbers in an array, then print them in reverse order. I have to pass the array and elements as parameters.

For the function getInput() everything worked out fine. I think at least. However, for the function printResults() I ran into a build time error that I can't seem to fix or understand.

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void getInput(double[], int);
void printResults(double[], int);

int main() {



    double userInput[10];

    getInput(userInput, 10);
    printResults(userInput, 10);

    return 0;
}

void getInput(double input[], int numElements)
{

    for(int i = 0; i < numElements; i++)
    {
        cout << "Please enter number " << (i + 1) << ": ";
        cin >> input[i];
    }
}

void printResult(double input[], int numElement)
{
    for(int i = 10; i > 0; --i)
    {
        cout << "Value number " << i << "is: " << input[i] << endl;
    }

}
```

And this is the error I keep running into

[image]

I may just be missing something simple, but Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Check your spelling.  There is a `printResult` function (no 's' suffix), and a call to `printResults` (with the trailing 's').  Spelling matters. :-)

Comment: There we go, I knew I was overlooking something! Thanks

Comment: Also, consider using std::vector, to avoid passing around a wrong size or forgetting to use the passed size (such as in your print function )

Comment: Also your `printResult` starts printing from `input[10]`. It should start from `input[9]` and also use your numElement argument

Comment: @Jonas I would but my assignment requires me to use arrays instead.

Comment: @linuxfever ya I overlooked that as well, never got to check that since my code wouldn't run! But Thank you!

Comment: @MohamedElmalah If the array size is known at compile time you could consider std::array, the C++ version of C arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call a function:

```
printResults
```

You implement a function:

```
printResult
```

Spelling matters. Notice one is a plural of the other.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from your main question, your array is of size 10 which means your biggest index is 9. And in your print results it appears that you're starting at 10 which would give it a runtime error/exception.